# Generation of coordinates from a range of values in matlab

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, coordinate-systems

```
  distance = [10:.1:30];
  norm_dist = normpdf(distance,20,2);
```

I am trying to generate x,y,z coordinates from the above range of normally distributed values but don't know how to do. Please help.
The normal_dist variable generates values in a normally distributed fashion. I want to use these values to randomly generate the x,y,z, coordinates values. The separate x,y,z values need to be generated not a 3-D array

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use meshgrid function as well

```
distance = [10:.1:30];
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(distance);
F = normpdf(X,20,2);
```

As a result you'll get 3d grid with those numbers

meshgrid() creates a matrix you can use for further calculations. Probably you will need to make normpdf dependent on X, Y, Z at the same time, e.g.

```
F = normpdf(X.^2+Y.^2+Z.^2,20,2)
```

Comment: Bro, I appreciate your help but I want separate x,y,z coordinates not a 3-D grid.

Comment: Hi, so maybe you should look at mvnpdf() function? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html
@ShankarDayalMishra